# Why for loop is working with one data set, yet error of replacement has length zero with very similar data set r

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a for loop, as shown below, which yields

> Error in v2[names(n_cl)[i]][[1]][j] <- cnv_gene_expr[names(n_cl)[i], gsub("_",  : 
>     replacement has length zero".

This occurs when I use the list, `n_cl`. However, when I use the list, `cl`, which is virtually the same in structure, the code works perfectly. What is missing here?

For loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(n_cl)){
  for(j in 1:length(n_cl[[i]])){
    v2[names(n_cl)[i]][[1]][j] = cnv_gene_expr[names(n_cl)[i], gsub("_",".",n_cl[names(n_cl)[i]][[1]][j])]
  }
}
```

a bit of what cl looks like:

```
$ABCC10
[1] "TCGA_DD_A1EG" "TCGA_FV_A3R2" "TCGA_FV_A3I0" "TCGA_DD_A1EH" "TCGA_FV_A23B"

$ACBD6
[1] "TCGA_DD_A1EH" "TCGA_DD_A3A8" "TCGA_ES_A2HT" "TCGA_DD_A1EG" "TCGA_DD_A1EB"
```

a bit of what n_cl looks like:

```
$ABCC10
[1] "TCGA_BC_A10Q" "TCGA_DD_A1EB" "TCGA_DD_A1EI" "TCGA_DD_A3A6" "TCGA_DD_A3A8" "TCGA_ES_A2HT"

$ACBD6
[1] "TCGA_BC_A10Q" "TCGA_DD_A1EI" "TCGA_DD_A3A6" "TCGA_FV_A23B" "TCGA_FV_A3I0" "TCGA_FV_A3R2"
```

a bit of what cnv_gene_expr looks like:

```
       TCGA.BC.A10Q TCGA.DD.A1EB TCGA.DD.A1EG TCGA.DD.A1EH TCGA.DD.A1EI TCGA.DD.A3A6 TCGA.DD.A3A8
ABCC10     2.540764    0.4372165     2.193205     3.265756    0.6060301     2.927072    0.6799514
ACBD6      1.112432    0.4611697     1.274129     1.802985   -0.0475743     1.071064    0.4336301
       TCGA.ES.A2HT TCGA.FV.A23B TCGA.FV.A3I0 TCGA.FV.A3R2
ABCC10  -0.08129554    2.2963764     3.196518    0.8595943
ACBD6    1.76935812    0.3644397     1.392206    1.0282030
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what are you trying to do in that loop? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: In this loop, I am trying to replace terms from cnv_gene_expr into cl and n_cl accordingly. For example, if cl$ABCC10 is "TCGA_DD_A1EG", I want to replace that with "2.540764" from column ""TCGA_DD_A1EG" row "ABCC10" of cnv_gene_expr. @RonakShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your data

```
df <- structure(list(TCGA.BC.A10Q = c(2.540764, 1.112432), TCGA.DD.A1EB = c(0.4372165, 
0.4611697), TCGA.DD.A1EG = c(2.193205, 1.274129), TCGA.DD.A1EH = c(3.265756, 
1.802985), TCGA.DD.A1EI = c(0.6060301, -0.0475743), TCGA.DD.A3A6 = c(2.927072, 
1.071064), TCGA.DD.A3A8 = c(0.6799514, 0.4336301), TCGA.ES.A2HT = c(-0.08129554, 
1.76935812), TCGA.FV.A23B = c(2.2963764, 0.3644397), TCGA.FV.A3I0 = c(3.196518, 
1.392206), TCGA.FV.A3R2 = c(0.8595943, 1.028203)), .Names = c("TCGA.BC.A10Q", 
"TCGA.DD.A1EB", "TCGA.DD.A1EG", "TCGA.DD.A1EH", "TCGA.DD.A1EI", 
"TCGA.DD.A3A6", "TCGA.DD.A3A8", "TCGA.ES.A2HT", "TCGA.FV.A23B", 
"TCGA.FV.A3I0", "TCGA.FV.A3R2"), row.names = c("ABCC10", "ACBD6"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
rownames(df) <- c("ABCC10", "ACBD6")

cl <- list(c("TCGA_DD_A1EG", "TCGA_FV_A3R2", "TCGA_FV_A3I0", "TCGA_DD_A1EH", "TCGA_FV_A23B"),
           c("TCGA_DD_A1EH", "TCGA_DD_A3A8", "TCGA_ES_A2HT", "TCGA_DD_A1EG", "TCGA_DD_A1EB"))
names(cl) <- c("ABCC10", "ACBD6")

n_cl <- list(c("TCGA_BC_A10Q", "TCGA_DD_A1EB", "TCGA_DD_A1EI", "TCGA_DD_A3A6", "TCGA_DD_A3A8", "TCGA_ES_A2HT"),
             c("TCGA_BC_A10Q", "TCGA_DD_A1EI", "TCGA_DD_A3A6", "TCGA_FV_A23B", "TCGA_FV_A3I0", "TCGA_FV_A3R2"))
names(n_cl) <- c("ABCC10", "ACBD6")
```

#### Solution

Need to modify your strings in `cl` and `n_cl`

```
newcl <- lapply(cl, function(x) gsub("_", ".", x))
newncl <- lapply(n_cl, function(x) gsub("_", ".", x))
```

The output you want

```
library(dplyr)
anscl <- lapply(1:length(newcl), function(x) unlist(filter(df, rownames(df) == names(newcl)[x]))[newcl[[x]]])
ansncl <- lapply(1:length(newncl), function(x) unlist(filter(df, rownames(df) == names(newncl)[x]))[newncl[[x]]])
names(anscl) <- c("ABCC10", "ACBD6")
names(ansncl) <- c("ABCC10", "ACBD6")
```

#### Output

```
anscl
$ABCC10
TCGA.DD.A1EG TCGA.FV.A3R2 TCGA.FV.A3I0 TCGA.DD.A1EH TCGA.FV.A23B 
   2.1932050    0.8595943    3.1965180    3.2657560    2.2963764 

$ACBD6
TCGA.DD.A1EH TCGA.DD.A3A8 TCGA.ES.A2HT TCGA.DD.A1EG TCGA.DD.A1EB 
   1.8029850    0.4336301    1.7693581    1.2741290    0.4611697


ansncl
$ABCC10
TCGA.BC.A10Q TCGA.DD.A1EB TCGA.DD.A1EI TCGA.DD.A3A6 TCGA.DD.A3A8 TCGA.ES.A2HT 
  2.54076400   0.43721650   0.60603010   2.92707200   0.67995140  -0.08129554 

$ACBD6
TCGA.BC.A10Q TCGA.DD.A1EI TCGA.DD.A3A6 TCGA.FV.A23B TCGA.FV.A3I0 TCGA.FV.A3R2 
   1.1124320   -0.0475743    1.0710640    0.3644397    1.3922060    1.0282030
```

Comment: $ABCC10
[1] 2.1932050 0.8595943 3.1965184 3.2657558 2.2963764

$ACBD6
[1] 1.8029846 0.4336301 1.7693581 1.2741289 0.4611697

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested Map function to test for the names after modifying your string names:

```
 Map(function(i,j) i[names(i)%in%j],split(df,row.names(df)),Map(gsub,"_",".",cl))
 $ABCC10
       TCGA.DD.A1EG TCGA.DD.A1EH TCGA.FV.A23B TCGA.FV.A3I0 TCGA.FV.A3R2 
  ABCC10  2.1932050    3.2657560    2.2963764    3.1965180    0.8595943 

 $ACBD6
       TCGA.DD.A1EB TCGA.DD.A1EG TCGA.DD.A1EH TCGA.DD.A3A8 TCGA.ES.A2HT 
  ACBD6   0.4611697    1.2741290    1.8029850    0.4336301    1.7693581 

   Map(function(i,j) i[names(i)%in%j],split(df,row.names(df)),Map(gsub,"_",".",n_cl))
 $ABCC10
         TCGA.BC.A10Q TCGA.DD.A1EB TCGA.DD.A1EI TCGA.DD.A3A6 TCGA.DD.A3A8 TCGA.ES.A2HT 
  ABCC10    2.54076400   0.43721650   0.60603010   2.92707200   0.67995140  -0.08129554 

 $ACBD6
         TCGA.BC.A10Q TCGA.DD.A1EI TCGA.DD.A3A6 TCGA.FV.A23B TCGA.FV.A3I0 TCGA.FV.A3R2 
  ACBD6     1.1124320   -0.0475743    1.0710640    0.3644397    1.3922060    1.0282030
```

Comment: I dont understand which variables I should use or where I should place this funciton

Comment: Sorry.  The cl and n_cl are the lst and lst1 respectively.  All the rest remain unchanged